# Google Sheet add increment numbers for duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello how to get a increment numbers for duplicate with array function.

Example in below picture if we search a word in entire `A` row if there is any duplicates it will add numbers in `B`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=arrayformula(if(A1:A="",,
A1:A&if(countif(A1:A,A1:A)=1,,
"-"&text(countifs(A1:A,A1:A,row(A1:A),"<="&row(A1:A)),"00"))))
```

[image]

Or...

```
=A1&if(countif(A$1:A,A1)=1,,
"-"&text(countif(A$1:A1,A1),"00"))
```

...and dragdown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Count duplicates

```
function countdups() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  let uA = [];
  let obj = {pA:[]};
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if(!~uA.indexOf(r[0])) {
      uA.push(r[0]);
      obj[r[0]] = 1;
      obj.pA.push(r[0]);
    } else {
      obj[r[0]] += 1;
    }
  });
  let vo = obj.pA.map(p => [`${p}-${obj[p]}`]);
  sh.getRange(1,2,vo.length,1).setValues(vo);
}
```

| COL1 | COL1-1 |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 7-2 |
| 6 | 6-1 |
| 9 | 9-1 |
| 11 | 11-3 |
| 16 | 16-1 |
| 4 | 4-1 |
| 15 | 15-1 |
| 19 | 19-3 |
| 11 | 2-1 |
| 2 | 10-3 |
| 10 | 18-1 |
| 11 | 5-1 |
| 10 | 0-1 |
| 18 |  |
| 19 |  |
| 19 |  |
| 10 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 0 |  |
| 7 |  |